# Javascript Excel OpenFile

Tags: javascript, excel, internet-explorer-11

I have this code:

```
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
      var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
      Excel.Workbook.Open("teste.xlsx");
    }
  </script>

  <body>

    <form name="form1">
      <input type=button onClick="test();" value="Open File">
      <br><br>
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

So the main problem is I keep getting this error:

```
On line 7 , Unable to get value of property Open
URL file:///C:/users/admin/desktop/test.hta
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, try moving your script to the bottom of the body. You should also set your `Excel` variable to be visible. And there's a typo with the line `Excel.Workbook.Open("teste.xlsx");` (should be `Workbooks`). The following is working for me in IE. I don't think it will work in other browsers:

```
<html>

  <body>

    <form name="form1">
      <input type=button onClick="test()" value="Open File">
      <br><br>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function test() {
        var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
        Excel.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbooks.Open("teste.xlsx");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will most definently not work in other browsers. But then again, been a long time since I made any HTAs.

Comment: well it was not as easy at it looks for me i changed the c0de for : 

`code`
Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\teste.xlsx");
`code`

otherwise it just open a blank excel file

Answer (score 1):

This work with IE 11 and you have to enable all the ActiveX controls in the Internet options.
This will open the excel and open the exact sheet what you mentioned in the sheet name.

```
<form name="form1">
  <input type=button onClick="test()" value="Open File">
  <br><br>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function test() 
  {  
    var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");  
    Excel.Visible = true; Excel.Workbooks.open("c:\\jeba\\sample.xlsx");  
    var excel_sheet = Excel.Worksheets("sheetname_1");  
    excel_sheet.activate();  
  }   
</script>
```