# Open excel for writing

Tags: javascript

I want to open a existing excel file,write values from array(create) and close from client side.
I used the below code:

```
for (var c=0; c<arrMCN.length; c++)
{
var mcnCreate = arrMCN[c];

var mcnNumber =mcnCreate.getProperty("agu2a_nb");
var mcnType=mcnCreate.getProperty("pdm_ecn_type");
var mcnProjectCode=mcnCreate.getProperty("pdm_project_code");
var mcnState=mcnCreate.getProperty("state");

var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
Excel.Visible = true;
Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\test.xls");
Excel.Activesheet.Cells(1,1).Value = mcnNumber;
var data =  Excel.Activesheet.Cells(1,1).Value;
return data;

}
```

I get "ActiveX component cannot create an object" error.
After changing the security in Internet option i didnt get the error.

Currently, I checked with to write just 1 value and it is written in the excel. 
Now I want to know how to write all the datas from the array into the excel.

Thanks

Comment: OS? IE version? A Metro app? Do you have Excel installed? Running locally or via web? Have you set all the needed options of a correct zone? Why is the path in `Workbooks.Open()` invalid?

Comment: sorry for the late response. I was not able to add comment or reply from yesterday. I have also raised his issue to the moderators and they are looking into this issue. I installed firefox to check if it works, luckily its working now.

Comment: OS Windows 7. Excel 2010.Running from web. Im using ARAS, and trying to export the Report from aras into excel on a button click event.

Comment: There's a bunch of options at Security tab's Internet zone to check correctly. Notice, that all of them should not be the top check. When these are correctly set and Excel is installed, you should not have any problems. You can also try to mark your site as trusted. After lowering security level, you should not visit any other sites than those you really can trust. Personally, I'd never allow ActiveX via web, and it's hard to imagine, how you could convince your users to do so. And fix the path, ofcourse. Please add the information from the comment above to your question too.

Comment: I tried to change the security settings,  but still have the same error.Is there any other way in which I can export a report to excel?

Comment: You can download a file, and do it using Excel manually. Btw. The path is still invalid, and no additional information can be seen ; ).

Comment: I changed the IE options and it works now, but its not the right way of doing... Is there another way to export in excel without activating the ActiveX controls? Thanks for your support.

Comment: Umh ...sorry,  mixed import/export. You can use `<input type="file">` and upload the file to your server, then handle it there. I'm not aware of any other direct export methods than ActiveX, but you can do some search on web ...

Comment: Im not able to produce the values in the array. It writes in excel but the data is not good. The array contains Item. How to convert to string? I tried toSting() and toSource(), with no good result.

Comment: You could create a form, include the values to inputs and submit the form  (that you're supposed to use when you're uploading a file as well) or use AJAX to pass the data. But this is actually not related to the original post, please post a new question.

Comment: I have posted a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
   Excel.Visible = true;
   Excel.Workbooks.Open("C:test.xls");
   var excel_sheet = excel_file.Worksheets("Sheet11");
   var data = excel_sheet.Cells(1,1).Value = create;
   return data;
```

and did it call URL properly :`C:test.xls` Check Using Some Alert Function

Comment: What is setting `Excel.Visible` worth of, if `Excel` was never created?

Comment: Better go how to open may be your file will not open thats why it creats problem for write:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246837/javascript-excel-openfile

Comment: When reading the question "`I get "ActiveX component cannot create an object" error.`" your answer and the linked post seems to be quite irrelevant.

Comment: TheC:test was a typo error. I changed the path to make it simple to put in the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the working solution for my question.

```
var Excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var checkFile= fso.FileExists("C:\\Report.xlsx");
if(checkFile)
{
fso.DeleteFile("C:\\Report.xlsx",true);
}
var ExcelSheet=new ActiveXObject("Excel.Sheet");
var offset=0;
var row=2;
for (var c=0; c<arrToExcel.length; c++)
{
var createExcel = arrToExcel[c];
var Number =createExcel.getProperty("number");
var Type=createExcel.getProperty("type");
var Code=createExcel.getProperty("code");
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("A" + (row + 1 +  offset)).Value = Number;
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("B" + (row + 1 + offset)).Value = Type;
ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet.Range("C" + (row + 1 + offset)).Value = Code;
row=row+1;
}
offset=offset+1;
Excel.DisplayAlerts=false;
ExcelSheet.SaveAs("C:\\EcnExcelReport.xlsx");
ExcelSheet.Application.Quit();
Excel.DisplayAlerts=true;
```

Thanks to all who suggested.