# How to convert readable stream to excel file object?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to fetch some Excel file from API and parse it, however, I am stuck at reading ReadableStream.
Here's what I fetch:

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://ukrstat.gov.ua/operativ/operativ2013/fin/kp_reg/kp_reg_u/xls_u/kp_reg_u_2018.xlsx');
  console.log(response);
};

fetchData();
```

I am using React so it'd be nice to have some advice how to proceed this information with [XLSX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

Comment: I cannot tell you how to make it to excel but I can tell you the secret of fetch, the readable stream (your response) has its own decoding methods. `fetch(url).then((byteStream) => byteStream.json()).then((decodedData) =>  console.log(decodedData))` in this example I use the json method, but there are more, text for example. You should use this technique to get proper data from your response. Note these methods are async, hence the second `then`

Comment: try `let txt = await response.text()` and see if you can work with that

Comment: @TheFool well, with this I get some kind of HTML markup.

Comment: are you sure this is not how raw xlsx looks like?

Comment: why not using this approach? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15246837/javascript-excel-openfile/15247150

Comment: @Vasyl Butov, did you manage to figure this, i need to do something similar.

Comment: @opensource-developer yes, I have. Do you need JSON or Blob ?

Comment: @opensource-developer https://github.com/Loctary/diplom/blob/master/src/pages/main/index.jsx#L19 here's how I parsed it using XLSX library, but if u'd like a Blob you may use Axios and specify responseType, and then ```const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' });``` (see type in response header) with resolved in promise data. Hope this helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I solved this specified problem:

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://ukrstat.gov.ua/operativ/operativ2013/fin/kp_reg/kp_reg_u/xls_u/kp_reg_u_2018.xlsx');
  return response;
};

const parseExcel = async () => {
  const stream = await fetchData();
  const arrayBuffer = await stream.arrayBuffer();
  const data = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  const arr = new Array();
  for (let i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
  const bstr = arr.join('');
  const workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, { type: 'binary' });
  const sheet = workbook.Sheets;
  const sheetName = Object.keys(sheet)[0];
  const json = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName], { header: 1 });
  console.log(json);
};

parseExcel();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/jszip.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.8.0/xlsx.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer. f i understand correctly, you load the contents of file in buffer all at once. Did you try with streams. I am having difficulty getting it to work with streams